# Convert PDF to Image file in web application using ASP.NET Core 3.1 app

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I do have a web application running in ASP.NET Core 3.1. The use case would be a user will upload a `.pdf` file and that file will be received as `IFormfile`. The file will then be converted to an image file (`.jpg/.png`). The file will then be uploaded to a blob storage.

I have looked into Pdfium but I think this is limited to desktop applications.

Do you have any other tools that worked for you? Any tips on how this can be achieved in web application?

Comment: Why do you want this in the first place? It matters. You can't just convert a PDF file to an image. A PDF is a file containing print instructions in PostScript. You need to *render* those instructions to an image, using a specific resolution. The resulting image will be a lot larger than the PDF itself. Are you trying to generate thumbnails perhaps?

Comment: BTW .NET Core 3.1 is way past its End Of Life. The oldest supported .NET Core version is .NET 6

Comment: I agree with @Panagiotis, why would you do that? It will be preferable to either collect jpg.png and store the blob. if you wish, it is easier to convert images to pdf than the other way round.

Comment: Does the PDF contain one or multiple pages? This matters too. Neither JPG nor PNG support multiple pages. Only TIFF does.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos the web application is already running and as additional requirement, they would like to have the pdf file to be converted to an image file.
Their pdf file only contains one page per file. 
The goal is to convert it to an  jpg or png file and not the thumbnail.

Comment: Hi @DavidMeshak I do agree with that but there was a requirement added to be able to upload a pdf file and have it convert it to image file.